# CakePHP- DateTime and php's date()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, datetime

I have a `datetime` field type in one table inside the db, which represent the start date and time of  an event.

I want to execute something as follows:

```
$taken_timeslots = $this->Schedule->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('start_at')) => $today)
));
```

where `start_at` is my database field, and $today is

```
$today = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $day_timestamp);
```

Basically I want to fetch all records which fall under 'today' . I would prefer if I use cake's find() method rather than query(), but will take anything into consideration, especially if a good answer is given! Thanks a heaps!

Comment: @BillyBigPotatoes Thanks for the reformatting, but can you help me out with the question  aswell :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, since your $today is the date you are looking for. First you must specify your field in the db:

```
$taken_timeslots = $this->Schedule->find('all', array(
   'conditions' => array('Date(Schedule.start_at)' => $today)
));
```

EDIT: I copied your code, there was one ) where there shouldn't be one :) Try now.

And this can be any day you want like this:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('29 September 2013'));
```

Comment: Mr skywalker, is this syntax correct? As this query is executed in an ajax request. and it is giving me a `500 internal error` with this query. Im sure its a problem with the query because if I comment it out, server gives  `200 OK response`

Comment: unfortunately the problem persists.. Ok, the problem with response  500 error was not the statement as I thought. But it is the query. I had a hasOne relation ship which was causing a column not found sql error. However, the above query still doesnt return any matches..

Comment: And I think it is incorrect because php's date function expects UNIX timestamp.. correct me if im wrong :)

Comment: I still don't know what is the `$day_timestamp` for, if your field is datetime in db, and you want today you can just use `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')` for today.

Comment: You are right, the variable name isn't really the best, but today is not really today, it is the unix timestamp for the day the user clicked on the calendar. Sorry for that..(in my mind: `today in the context of the function`)

Comment: You can format dates easily, I'm not sure what your calendar returns as the date, but you can format it to suit your needs, there is one example in recent edit to the answer.

Comment: Just so you know, your code worked. For some reason, I wasn't getting any results from the db until I cleared cache and cookies. Thanks mate